# Auto suggest only on entering 3 characters

Tags: php, jquery

This code displays autosuggest on entering 1 character. How can change the autosuggest to work only on typing min of 3 characters

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#main-keywords").keyup(function(){
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "readkeyword.php",
        data:'keyword='+$(this).val(),
        beforeSend: function(){
            $("main-keywords").css("background","#FFF url(LoaderIcon.gif) no-repeat 165px");
        },
        success: function(data){
            $("#suggesstion-box").show();
            $("#suggesstion-box").html(data);
            $("#main-keywords").css("background","#FFF");
        }
        });
    });
});

function selectCountry(val) {
$("#main-keywords").val(val);
$("#suggesstion-box").hide();
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Count length of characters entered in `#main-keywords` with `.length` as shown :-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#main-keywords").keyup(function(){
      if($(this).val().length > 2) // add this line
      {
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "readkeyword.php",
        data:'keyword='+$(this).val(),
        beforeSend: function(){
            $("main-keywords").css("background","#FFF url(LoaderIcon.gif) no-repeat 165px");
        },
        success: function(data){
            $("#suggesstion-box").show();
            $("#suggesstion-box").html(data);
            $("#main-keywords").css("background","#FFF");
        }
        });
     }
    });
});
```

Comment: @Aravind..happy to help you..;)

Answer (score 0):

Check length of characters before ajax :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#main-keywords").keyup(function(){
        var len = $(this).length; // get length here

      if(len >= 3) { // if 3 characters entered..proceed
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "readkeyword.php",
        data:'keyword='+$(this).val(),
        beforeSend: function(){
            $("main-keywords").css("background","#FFF url(LoaderIcon.gif) no-repeat 165px");
        },
        success: function(data){
            $("#suggesstion-box").show();
            $("#suggesstion-box").html(data);
            $("#main-keywords").css("background","#FFF");
        }
        });
      }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you've got the answer, I'm writing this for the future readers and for you to do optimization.

In your code, What you're doing is making AJAX request for every character you type or delete in the text-box. This is kind of bad practice as you will be making too many async server requests at a time. This might leads to too much load on server.

What you need to do is make server request only when user pause for some time after writing into the text-box.

You can use https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote for this, they have handled this very well.

For JSON data type : https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp